# Change amount of orders shown per page in account

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, frontend, customer-account

The default amount of orders shown in the Magento account page in Frontend is 10. Also you have the option to show 20 or 50 orders in the table. I want to set the default to 50 or maybe even 100 orders shown. Also i want to achieve this for the product reviews.

Please see screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Missing a lot of details, which magento version. in the backend, your screenshot does not look like a current back-end?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply, As it is in the frontend of the account page, the url will be: /sales/order/history/.

Magento version is 1.9.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Go and find the layout xml related to that page and add the following code to it. Clear cache and see the changes.

Go and find the sales.xml in the layout of your theme. or copy it from the original and add it to you local theme.

then find

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
```

and inside that you will find

```
<block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
```

there add a action like this

```
<action method="setDefaultLimit">
    <limit>100</limit>
</action>
```

so you get something like this

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order View</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info">
            <block type="sales/order_info_buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" />
        </block>
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="setDefaultLimit">
                      <limit>100</limit>
              </action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" class="a-right"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>view</name><path></path><label>Order Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>creditmemo</name><path>*/*/creditmemo</path><label>Refunds</label></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</sales_order_view>
```

That should do the trick
don't forget to clean cache

Comment: I tried your solution. I copied the sales.xml file to: /app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout. But nothing changed. After that i replaced my code part with your part of the code, but still no change. I empty the cache a few times and entered thru private window, but nothing seem to change.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?